# React Formik - Trigger validation only on form submit

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-native, formik, yup

I am using Formik in my React Native application. On the login form I have two fields: email and password, both of them are required.

I've written such validation rules:

```
export const LoginSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  email: Yup.string()
    .email('The email is invalid')
    .required('This field is required'),
  password: Yup.string()
    .min(6, 'The password is too short')
    .max(12, 'The password is too long')
    .required('This field is required'),
});
```

I need to trigger validation ONLY on form submit and show an error popup. I've read the docs, but can't find a solution because the validation triggers onBlur. How can this be done?

Thanks!

```
const Login = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Later check for token
    const tokenIsStored = true;

    if (tokenIsStored) {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  });

  const onLogin = values => {
    console.log(values, 'on login');

    // Pass value to BE endpoint
    navigation.navigate('Dashboard');
  };

  const onModalClose = () => {
    setIsVisible(false);
  };

  console.log(isVisible);

  if (!isLoading) {
    return (
      <ScrollContainer keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled">
        <ThemedStatusBar />

        <ThemedModal
          isVisible={isVisible}
          primaryMessage="Log In Failed"
          secondaryMessage="Please check your password"
          btnTitle="OK"
          btnPress={() => onModalClose()}
        />

        <Formik
          initialValues={{ email: '', password: '' }}
          validationSchema={LoginSchema}
          onSubmit={values => onLogin(values)}
        >
          {props => (
            <View>
              <ScrollContainer BackgroundColor={Colors.greyColor} Padding="0px" style={styles.loginForm}>
                <ThemedInput
                  onChangeText={props.handleChange('email')}
                  onBlur={props.handleBlur('email')}
                  value={props.values.email}
                  placeholder="Email"
                  keyboardType="email-address"
                />
                <ThemedInput
                  onChangeText={props.handleChange('password')}
                  onBlur={props.handleBlur('password')}
                  value={props.values.password}
                  placeholder="Password"
                  overrideStyles={styles.loginInputBottom}
                  secureTextEntry
                />
                {props.errors.email && setIsVisible(true)}
              </ScrollContainer>
              <ThemedButton onPress={props.handleSubmit} title="Log In" />
            </View>
          )}
        </Formik>
      </ScrollContainer>
    );
  }
  return <ThemedLoader isLoading />;
};

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 132, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://formik.org/docs/guides/validation#when-does-validation-run)

> You can control when Formik runs validation by changing the values of `<Formik validateOnChange>` and/or `<Formik validateOnBlur>` props depending on your needs.

Pass to your `Formik` the props `validateOnChange={false}` and `validateOnBlur={false}`

Answer (score 43):

Yeah. You can do something like this.

```
<Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        validateOnChange={false}
        validateOnBlur={false}
        onSubmit={(values, { validate }) => {
            validate(values);
        }}
    >
```

Comment: where is the validate() function coming from?

Comment: @anastymous in comment above is generated by Formik from validationSchema.

Comment: Latest version of Formik uses validateForm for the FormikHelpers.

Answer (score 24):

If you use useFormik hook, the next config should be added

```
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues,
    validationSchema,
    validateOnChange: false, // this one
    validateOnBlur: false, // and this one
    onSubmit: (values) => {
     do something on submit
    },
  });
```